# laravel route error class not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new to the Laravel framework and I am stuck with routing.

Folder structure:

```
app  
     controllers\ 
                   admin\ authcontroller.php
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('admin/logout', array('as' =>'admin.logout', 'uses'=>'App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController@getLogout' ));
Route::get('admin/login', array('as' =>'admin.login' , 'uses'=>'App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController@getLogin' ));
Route::get('admin/login',array('as'=>'admin.login.post','uses'=>'App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController@postLogin'));

Route::group( array('prefix' =>'admin' ,'before'=>'auth.admin' ),function (){

    Route::any('/','App\Controllers\Admin\PagesController@index');

    Route::resource('articles','APP\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController');
    Route::resource('pages','App\Controllers\Admin\PagesController');

});
```

authcontroller.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Controllers\Admin

use Auth, BaseController, Form, Input, Redirect, Sentry, View;

class Authcontroller extends BaseController
{
    public function getLogin(){
      die('here');
        return  View::make('admin.auth.login');
    }
    public function postLogin(){
         $credentials= array(
            'email' =>Input::get('email') ,
            'password'=>Input::get('password'),
             );

         try{

            $user=Sentry::authenticate($credentials,FALSE);
            if($user){
                return  Redirect::route('admin.pages.index');
            }
         }

         catch (Exception $e){
            return  Redirect::route('admin.login')->withErrors(array('login' => $e->getMessage() ));

         }
    }
    /*
      logout function
    */

      public function  getLogout(){
         Sentry::logout();
         return  Redirect::route('admin.login');
      }
}
```

Error:

> Class App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController does not exist

what is make that error appear

also when i run composer dump-autoload from the CMD
i did not found the namespace loaded in autoload_namespaces.php file

Comment: Is that the correct namespace you put the controller?

Comment: i use this in my controller
namespace App\Controller\Admin

use Auth, BaseController, Form, Input, Redirect, Sentry, View;

Comment: did you do a composer dump-autoload? Also, you spelt "Controller", not "Controllers", so try with \App\Controller\Admin\AuthController@method

Comment: when i make composer dump-autoload  the namespace does not appear in the autoload_namespaces.php
also i can not understand the second part of your solution more details please

Answer (score 0):

You have a typing error. Your controllers name is "Authcontroller" and in your Route it is "AuthController". Or have you see this already?

Comment: i have changed the name of the route to be the same as the controller

and the error still there
Class App\Controllers\Admin\Authcontroller does not exist

Comment: Have you dumpautoload -o again? Now you write again "Authcontroller"!? Use you PSR-0 or PSR-4 in your composer.json?

Comment: i get this error
syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) or ';' or '{'
in controller
namespace App\Controllers\Admin
 
use Auth, BaseController, Form, Input, Redirect, Sentry, View;

Comment: This is good. Now the controller will be found. The new error says you have a error in the controller itself. In most cases this is a ":" instead of a ";" or a missing ";". When you don't find it, post the controller file. Than I can take a closer look.

Comment: I see above the controller fiel. The ";" after the namespace is missing.